# How to test two websites in one session

Tags: cypress

We are working on a muti-tier service driven projects.
CRM driven UI project is used to set a rules engine. (UI - We automate this using Cypress.io)

It takes few minutes for change to get reflected in End-user facing Frontend-app (Its also separately covers by Cypress.io framework)

We would like to have e2e UI tests, which starts first on Rules engine and same test should wait for few minutes & then continue to check the affect on Frontend UI

In selenium we could do something like -

```
driver.get("http://www.siteA.com/rules");//internal rules engine CRM
..
..    
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
..
..
driver.get("http://www.siteB.com/public");//customer facing Frontend
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar in Cypress.io

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I created a workaround for this issue, and It's working fine for me.

Use this code when you want to navigate to another URL while your test is running:

```
cy.document().then((doc) => {
 doc.location.replace(newUrlHere)
})
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael! Your solution worked great! It should be in cypress documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the same "session" from completely different servers.

only done with a Single Sign.

the different servers in order to get some kind of certification of the identity of the user.

Basically OpenID, e.g. used here on stackoverflow, is a solution to the same problem, though you usually don't have implicit login - you need to explicitly log in.

If you control both participating servers as well as the authenticating "third party" (which may in fact be part of one of the two servers) you should be able to provide some implicit login easily.

Be aware of possible privacy issues though, if the sites don't obviously belong together. People might feel alienated if you proactively shared their identity if they don't recognize that both servers belong to the same entity

Answer (score 0):

If you try to go to two different domains Cypress will respond with this message:

> CypressError: cy.visit() failed because you are attempting to visit a
>   second unique domain.
>
> You may only visit a single unique domain per test.
>
> Different subdomains are okay, but unique domains are not.
>
> The previous domain you visited was:
>   'https://s3-portal.sqills-deep-purple-test.cloud.sqills.com'
>
> You're attempting to visit this new domain: 'http://www.google.com'
>
> You may need to restructure some of your code to prevent this from
>   happening.
>
> https://on.cypress.io/cannot-visit-second-unique-domain

So you have to be on the same domain. For example this works:

```js
it.only('test', function () {
    cy.visit('https://images.google.com')
    cy.contains('Google')
    cy.wait(500)
    cy.visit('https://google.com')
    cy.contains('Google')
  })
```

This way it is possible to test two different including a wait which you can set.